# How can I represent implementation of a pattern in a UML class diagram?

Tags: oop, uml

In UML, how can I represent that a class implements some design pattern or follows some convention?  For example, in Java, that a class follows the JavaBean convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stereotypes f.e. <<javabean>>
Or use notes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a note to the diagram, pointing to the section that implements the pattern.

Or your could use the extensibility system in UML known as stereotypes.  Add `<<javabean>>` to all classes that implement that pattern.

Follow the UML rules as much as possible but just remember that it is designed to be extensible so it should never hold you back from expressing your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about "Software Design Patterns", right ?

They are concepts that does not have an specific implementation on U.M.L.
As the prvious answers, they use the same stuff that allow U.M.L. to be extended, stereotypes, and notes.